# If $X, Y$ are random matrices, with $X$ independent of $Y$, is it true their sample covariances are independent as well?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose that $X$ is a $p \times n_1$ random matrix and $Y$ is a $p \times n_2$ random matrix in which $X$ is independent of $Y$. If I let $X_i$ and $Y_i$ denote the $i$th column of $X$ and $Y$, then the sample covariance matrix is defined as:

$$
S_X = \sum_{i=1}^{n_2} (X_i- \bar{X})(X_i- \bar{X})^T = XX^T - n_1\bar{X}\bar{X}^T
$$
and
$$
S_Y = \sum_{i=1}^{n_2} (Y_i- \bar{Y})(Y_i- \bar{Y})^T = YY^T - n_2\bar{Y}\bar{Y}^T
$$

It seems that since $\bar{X}$ and $\bar{Y}$ are independent, so should $S_X$ and $S_Y$. However, I cannot place a formal argument here. Could someone help me herE? Thanks.

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Functions_of_Independent_Random_Variables_are_Independent

Comment: To connect this to the proof, what should I view as the "random variable" here? Would it be the entire matrix or the columns of the matrix? Thanks!

Comment: $S_X$ is a measurable function from $\mathbb{R}^{p\times n_1}$ to $ \mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$ (the same for $S_Y$)...